# 'mutt' does not show full subject

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, quoting, mutt

I use following shell script to send email. But the subject of email always shows "This" instead of `"This is L_1.R"`.

```
    program=("L_1" "L_2" "L_3" "L_4")
    subject="The job is finished"
    ssh -f c15-0330-01.ad.mtu.edu 'echo' "the job ${program[0]} is finished"   '|' 'mutt "zwang10@mtu.edu" -s' "This is "${program[0]}".R";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First start with what you want the remote command to look like, with bare minimal quoting:

```
echo the job L_1 is finished | mutt zwang10@mtu.edu -s 'This is L_1.R'
```

There are only a couple of things you need to quote to have them passed literally to the remote shell: the pipe character, and quotes around the subject to make the spaces not split it into separate arguments to mutt.

```
program=("L_1" "L_2" "L_3" "L_4")
subject="The job is finished"
ssh -f c15-0330-01.ad.mtu.edu echo the job ${program[0]} is finished '|' mutt zwang10@mtu.edu -s "'"This is ${program[0]}.R"'";
```

With the longer command, do the same thing:

```
cd $address && nohup Rscript ${program[0]}.R > ${program[0]}_sh.txt && echo the job ${program[0]} is finished | mutt zwang10@mtu.edu -s 'This is ${program[0]}.R'
```

(only with the variables substituted).

Here, a few things need to be quoted:

```
ssh -f c15-0330-01.ad.mtu.edu cd $address '&&' nohup Rscript ${program[0]}.R '>' ${program[0]}_sh.txt '&&' echo the job ${program[0]} is finished '|' mutt zwang10@mtu.edu -s "'"This is ${program[0]}.R"'"
```

Comment: Could you help me to make it neatly `ssh -f c15-0330-01.ad.mtu.edu 'cd' "$address" '&& nohup Rscript' ""${program[0]}".R" '>' ""${program[0]}"_sh.txt" '&&' 'echo' "the job ${program[0]} is finished" '|' 'mutt "zwang10@mtu.edu" -s "This is "'${program[0]}'".R";'`

Comment: `address="/home/campus27/zwang10/Desktop/AWRR/program/power/vmodel_1/nprot/K_10"`

Comment: I notice you use `'"' '"'`. Can you explain more about it?

Comment: I put `\n` in the `echo`, but it does not work. `ssh -f ${host_list[0]} cd '"'$address'"' '&&' nohup Rscript ${program[0]}.R '>' ${program[0]}_sh.txt '&&' echo The job $address ${program[0]} \nis finished '|' mutt zwang10@mtu.edu -s "'"${host_list[0]} - Job ${program[0]}.R finished"'";`

Comment: you need the echo command to get a literal backslash and n, so you need to escape the backslash for the remote shell and you also need to escape it for the local shell.  so `'\\n'is finished` will work

Answer (score 0):

Move your single quote.

```
ssh -f c15-0330-01.ad.mtu.edu 'echo' "the job ${program[0]} is finished" \
'|' 'mutt "zwang10@mtu.edu" -s "This is "'${program[0]}'".R";'
```

EDIT: I put the variable out of the quotes. The main thing is spaces are covered.

Comment: I tried it, but it says `program: Undefined variable.` The reason that I do not put double quotes inside of single quotes is that I cannot define variable between single quotes.

Comment: I put `\n` in the `echo`, but it does not work. `ssh -f ${host_list[0]} cd '"'$address'"' '&&' nohup Rscript ${program[0]}.R '>' ${program[0]}_sh.txt '&&' echo The job $address ${program[0]} \nis finished '|' mutt zwang10@mtu.edu -s "'"${host_list[0]} - Job ${program[0]}.R finished"'";`